# Concatenating string array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an array of strings, with the following values;

```
public texto: string[] = []; =>

0: "Tacrolimus em adultos"
1: "Sugestão - p07"
2: "Anti-aging - B (oral)"
3: "Tomar duas vezes ao dia."
```

I need to concatenate each element of the array by jumping a line into a variable. This variable will be used to insert value into a textarea field. I am using logic for this, but without success.

```
this.texto.forEach(e => {
      const str = `${e} \n`;
      this.textoFormat.concat(str);
    });
```

Typescript =>

```
public formula: any;
  public medicamento: string[] = [];
  public sugestao: string[] = [];
  public composto: string[] = [];
  public texto: string[] = [];
  public textoFormat: string = 'Fórmula \n';

ngOnInit() {
    this.formula = this._formulaService.formulaSugeridaTexto;

    this.formula.medicamento.forEach(medicamento => {
      this.medicamento.push(medicamento.nome);
    });

    this.formula.sugestao.forEach(sugestao => {
      this.sugestao = sugestao.nome;
    });

    this.texto.push(this.formula.nome);
    this.texto.push(this.sugestao.toString());
    this.texto.push(this.medicamento.toString());
    this.texto.push(this.formula.modo_uso);

    this.texto.forEach(e => {
      const str = `${e} \n`;
      this.textoFormat.concat(str);
    });
  }
```

---

HTML =>

```
<ion-textarea rows="15" cols="20" [value]="textoFormat"> </ion-textarea>
```

I hope the output is:

```
Fórmula
    Tacrolimus em adultos
    Sugestão - p07
    Anti-aging - B (oral)
    Tomar duas vezes ao dia.
```

but nothing is being shown, only the string set by default "Formula"... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` method of `Array` like following:

```
this.textoFormat += this.texto.join('\n');
```

Comment: Hi Harun, Is there a need of +=? I think we can assign it directly.

Comment: Yes, indeed.`textoFormat` is initialized like this: `public textoFormat: string = 'Fórmula \n';` And the output contains `Formula \n` in the beginning